# Yii CPagination paging mixed data

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to render a view with mixed data in it with a pagination limit of 6 items per page.
In this case I have a Controller that renders a view and passes an array of mixed data such as an array of Catalogs and Products.

```
$products = new Products;
$productsCriteria = new CDbCriteria;

$catalogs = new Catalogs;
$catalogsCriteria = new CDbCriteria;

$productsCriteria->condition = "status = 1 AND category_id = :category_param";
$productsCriteria->params = array(':category_param' => $id); //$id is passed as a parameter to the action
$productsCriteria->order = "created_on DESC";

$catalogsCriteria->condition = "status = 1 AND category_id = :category_param";
$catalogsCriteria->params = array(':category_param' => $id);
$catalogsCriteria->order = "created_on DESC";

$productsCount = $products->count($productsCriteria);
$catalogsCount = $catalogs->count($catalogsCriteria);

$pages = new CPagination($productsCount + $catalogsCount);
$pages->pageSize = 6;
$pages->applyLimit($productsCriteria);
$pages->applyLimit($catalogsCriteria);

$productResult = $products->findAll($productsCriteria);
$catalogResult = $catalogs->findAll($catalogsCriteria);

$result = array_merge($productResult, $catalogResult);

$this->render('list', array('data' => $result, 'pages' => $pages, 'productsCount' => $productsCount, 'catalogsCount' => $catalogsCount));
```

This works as it is, but it renders 6 items of each type. It renders 6 Catalogs and then it renders 6 Products per page. What I need is that it renders all of the Catalogs first, 6 per page, regardless of how many pages it needs and then it renders all of the Products, again, 6 per page and regardless of how many pages it needs.

On another note, the Products and Catalogs are in a many to many relationship. I've also tried extracting Products the following way:

```
$productsCriteria->join = ", catalog_product_relation cpr WHERE status = 1 AND category_id = :category_param AND cpr.product_id != t.id";
```

I used the

```
cpr.products_id != t.id
```

since I need to list Products that don't belong to any Catalog.
I used join since it only appends the string to the criteria without adding any MySQL tokens like condition does.

Merging the two criteria doesn't work since they're different data models.

Comment: B, if *Merging the two criteria doesn't work since they're different data models.* then remove this line from your code here too.

Comment: Merging the criteria as in `$productsCriteria->mergeWith($catalogsCriteria);`. The `array_merge()` merges the resulting data into one array, which is not the issue.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve your goal with this flow. You have to have more custom query and user of CSqlDataProvider with CPagination

Comment: @G45, CSqlDataProvider wouldn't (doesn't I've tried) help either, as it returns only one set of data, I can select all the necessary data that I need, but it returns the data as a combined data item, as in `catalogs.*, products.*` as one array of data, but I need them separately as an array of Catalogs and Products that I can combine later and apply the pagination limit. If I'm wrong, which is 90% of the time, please provide me an example. Thanks.